# AJAX with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to incorporate a simple AJAX function with Django and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. `request.is_ajax()` is returning `False` and even when I do `event.preventDefault()`, the form is still being submitted.

Here is the view:

```
def search(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        search_text = request.POST.get('search_text', False)
    else:
        search_text = 'Not AJAX'
    return HttpResponse(search_text)
```

The JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('#search_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: {% url 'users:search' %},
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#search-results').html(data);
                },
            failure: function(data){
                alert('Got an error');
                }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

And the HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Search</h5>
            <form action="{% url 'users:search' %}" method="POST" id="search_form" name="search_form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
            <ul id="search-results">
                {% if users %}
                    {% for user in users %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'users:detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <p>No user available</p>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What's the url pattern for that view?

Comment: `url(r^'search/$',  views.search, name='search')`

Comment: As @ppetrid has commented in my answer, clarification about where your js code is, is needed.  It is in a html template? If the answer is yes, then please update your question in order to reflect that.

Comment: It's not in the template, the template tags were a silly mistake. After changing them, it still does not work correctly. Still sending me to the new page returning `Not AJAX`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the form is actually always submitted because you have an error in your js. In the `$ajax` options, the url should be surrounded with quotes:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '{% url 'users:search' %}',
    ...
});
```

In your question you say that `request.is_ajax` is `False`, which implies the ajax call is actually performed. I don't think that's the case here. Given the above code sample the call does not happen at all and none of the view code should be executed.

Comment: That didn't fix it. The view is executed. When the form submits it takes me to the url with the results printed. The result being `Not AJAX`

Comment: I can see why the request is not AJAX, since there is a traditional form submission. But I think there must be a javascript parse error there somewhere. It's something I come across quite often, due to a misspell or a minor parse error. The js code cannot execute and therefore it performs the default submit action. Try to add a void target in your html (<form action="javascript:void(0);" ...). That way there'll be no submission and you will be able to check for js errors in a tool like firebug or Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separated the js from the html, why are you using the template language in the js.

```
url: '{% url 'users:search' %}',
```

I think you should just do:

```
url: 'search',
```

Comment: Hello, I suspect the OP uses the above js code inside the template file, since he also prints the csrf token there. But that's a good point there that needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what went wrong.

I changed my JavaScript code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search_form').submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/users/search/',
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() // properly capture the CSRF Token
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#search-results').html(data);
                },
            failure: function(data){
                alert('Got an error');
                }
        });

    });
});
```

The error was the CSRF Token wasn't being sent with the rest of the data. Hopefully someone can find this useful down the road. Silly mistake by my part.

Comment: You can also user @csrf_exempt decorator to your view method as well if you don't want csrf validation on the post request.